# Clear inputs causes refresh of the page

Tags: jquery, forms

I made a function that uploads a file with 2 other fields for name and description of the file uploaded. With a progress bar. All Works fine, but when I want to clear inputs fields after the success, the entire page is reloaded. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('#frmUploadFile').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('#fileGivenName').val() == '') {
        alert('Please set a file name.');
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: root_url + "document/reception",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: new FormData(this),
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //$("#preview").fadeOut();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $('#fileMessageUpload').html(messageUploadSucceed).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
                $('#fileGivenName').val('');
                $('#fileDesc').val('');
                $('#fileName').val('');
            } else if (data.error) {
                messageUploadFailed += ':: ' + data.message;
                $('#fileMessageUpload').html(messageUploadFailed).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            messageUploadFailed += ':: ' + data.message;
            $('#fileMessageUpload').html(messageUploadFailed).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
})
```

If I remove theses lines it works but my fields are not cleared.

```
$('#fileGivenName').val('');
$('#fileDesc').val('');
$('#fileName').val('');
```

EDIT-----------------------
it seems that clearing cache and reload the page with CRTL or SHIFT works and stops the reload of the page BUT my fields weren't reset, so to resolve the problem i deleted the ';' at the end of lines and it works I don't know why:

```
if(data.success){
                    $('#fileMessageUpload').html(messageUploadSucceed).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow')
                    console.log('on est dans le success')
                    $('#fileGivenName').val('')
                    $('#fileDesc').val('')
                    $('#fileName').val('')
                }
```

Comment: The code you've quoted won't cause the behavior you're describing. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Agree with the above comment, clearing a field cannot cause a postback/refresh. Something else is causing it. Perhaps you changed something else in your code at the same time you added or removed those lines. Look back at what you did and try to test one small change at a time to find the problem.

Comment: I refreshed with CTRL and SHIFT, i cleared cache, the refresh disappear, BUT, the fields weren't clear, but the messageSuccess was display. So i retired ';' at the end of each lines, and it works! Why?